# Jsp will not display table with contents

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am working on a project with java servlets and JSP.

I have a java class that generates me a list of products, of type `List<Product>` and I saved the list in variable Products.

```
Ex:  List<Product> products = ProductIO.selectProducts();
```

To access the name description of each list I use. (print them to screen)

```
System.out.println(products.get(i).getDescription());
```

Okay! Now here comes the problem, I want to generate a table and place all items descriptions in there, However I get a blank table and I assume is bad syntax.

Here is my `products.jsp` code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Murach's Java Servlets and JSP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CD list</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>        
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}" varStatus ="i">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value='${product.get(i).getDescription}' /></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `System.out.println(products.get(i).getDescription());` is this gives you anything on console?

Comment: I would think you need to do either `${product.get(i).getDescription()}` or `${product.get(i).description}` rather than what you have there.

Comment: shoud be `product.description` ?

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh , Yeah, it prints out the name of CD fine inside the servlet.

Comment: I think you trying to iterate over var "product" instead of list "products", you can either try ${products.get(i).getDescription()} or ${product.description}.

Comment: `<c:out value="${product.description()}"` use this

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh I tried it, my table is empty.  I only have on browser CD list


Description

Comment: `<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${product.description}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>` assuming you have `description` as your variable in the `Product` class,Try this. Also let usknow how you are passing the data from your `java class` to `jsp`.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh This is inside my servlet .HttpSession s=request.getSession();
s.setAttribute("product",products);

Comment: try `request.setAttribute("product", products);`

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

`p_IO.selectProducts()` may be a `List<Product>` so you don't need to extract list within forEach. Try this:

```
....
<c:forEach items="${p_IO.selectProducts()}" var="product" >
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value='${product.description}' /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
....
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get empty. I tried that way and ${product.get(i).getDescription()} or ${product.get(i).description}.

Comment: have you tried `${products}` or `${products.size()}` or `out.print(request.getAttribute("products"))` ?

Comment: Thank you auntyellow! After all day battling with this. Your exact code above worked!